# MySql: select posts where tags do not repeat

Tags: mysql, select

I have 3 tables: post, tag and tag/post

I want to do a select that will give me all posts that do not have any of the tags repeated.

Eg:

Post 1-Tags: me, you, them

Post 2-Tags: others, you

Post 3-Tags: people, crowd

Expected result: Post 1, Post 3

Comment: did you try anything yet?

Comment: I tried parsing after results but it is a nightmare

Comment: maybe try a join of some kind (there are really only two kinds)

Comment: Why wouldn't the results be Post 2 and Post 3?

Comment: It could be. I would be fine with having Post 2 and Post 3 as a result.

Comment: I tried grouping by tag, doing a count and only returning all that are equal to one but then all that have the tag repeated don't return and I wanted one (the first or the last) to show

Comment: in Post 2 also no tag is repeated. then why the result would not be Post 1, Post 2 and Post 3?

Comment: Because Post 1 and Post 2 repeat the tag. That is what I am looking for, any of tags do not exist on previous posts

Comment: show your table structure

Comment: I never show first! Show me yours and if I like what I see, I'll show you mine :)